# Asus Strix Soar impedance config

Tags: audio

Do you know how to change impedance for discrete sound card asus strix soar for headphones? in Windows driver it is simple you just right click on headphones and choose between low medium and high. Should it be somewhere in alsamixer or i have to use other tool?
Asus Soar allows to adjust impedance up to 500ohm that's why i like it

Comment: You'd need a proprietary driver that isn't available for Linux. You may try asking the manufacturer. Good luck.

Comment: errr as someone coming from an electrical engineering / signal processing background: Which fresh marketing hell is "I can increase the impedance of my amplifier"? A high-impedance amplifier is *always* worse than a low-impedance one, as long as we're not talking radio frequencies. So my guess is that that switch on windows, if it actually did something, did actually do fancy distortion to make things sound differently on cheaper headphones. There's been a hundreds of these switches before with the most misleading names ("Dyna-bass", "Hypersound", "dynamic boost", "spatial maximization"…)

Comment: …or maybe it just shifts the gain range for higher-acoustic-efficiency speakers?